# Is it possible to Turn Location ON by device administrators programmatically without any dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-developer-api

Is it possible to Turn Location Services ON by programmatically, If an App got **Device Administrator** Permission?

I know, we can show **Location Settings Dialog** to turn on Location Services even without administrator permission. but I am looking for a way to turn location services on purely by codes.

Comment: does this mean you want to TURN ON say GPS using code? Or only want to enable location service ?

Comment: Location service. like the toggle button you see in notifications panel.

Comment: so you mean Turn on "Access to my location" check box without user's knowledge "secretly" via code? Not so sure if there is a Public API for this as you may imagine. It looks against the principle that apps should allow its user to decide rather than doing "privileged" operations directly

Comment: @AADTechnical I know, it is against privacy, but I already said, _"If an App got Device Administrator Permission"_ - User will allow this App as **Device Administrator**. So, I am looking for a way to achieve this by code after it got device administrator permission.

Comment: App being Device Administrator does not give it full freedom to tweak with user's privacy, IMHO. I still think user should be given choice by app to toggle such private info

Comment: @AADTechnical This is the constraint in my App.